# Delete observations a certain time period apart

Tags: datetime, sas, time-series

So I have a dataset that contains a stock ID and a date_time variable amongst other things. I would like to delete all observations for which the date_time variable is 30 minutes from the next date_time AND the stock is the same. So if my data set looked like this:

```
Date_Time|Stock_ID 
01APR11: 07:50:00|Treasury
01APR11: 07:51:00|Treasury
```

These two observations would be deleted. So far I am trying to mark them for deletion with the dif and lag functions. This is my code

```
data 3;
set 2; 
time_diff=dif(Date_Time)/60; 
same_stock=lag(Stock); 
delete=.;
if abs(time_diff)<=30 AND same_stock=Stock_ID then delete=1;
run;
```

After this point, i can just drop all observations where delete=1.
The problem is, I don't think this code is very efficient and it is definitely prone to error, especially if there are three date times all next to each other.

There must be a better way to do this.

Comment: How would you want to handle a series of entries for the same stock spanning > 60 minutes but with all the entries less than say 10 minutes apart? Delete them all?

Comment: yes I would want to delete them all.

Comment: I honestly don't think your existing approach is too bad, unless your dataset is massive and you're desperate to avoid reading it more than once. Is the dataset sorted in any particular order?

Comment: Yes so its sorted first by stock ID and then by time, which is why my solution can work. It's just pretty worrisome because I think its easily prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the dangerous aspect of original solution is that it is
 **not reading records for the stock in chronological order**, so the deletion can be influenced by the order of records in source data.

I'd recommend:
1) BY processing in datastep in chronological order
2) if you performance is critical, I' only output final records (once the logic is correct)

Btw, I wonder you really use numbers as table names.

```
/* sort data */
proc sort data=d2;
by stock Date_Time;
run;

/* or create index */
proc sql;
create index idx1 on d2 (stock Date_Time);
quit;

/* or create view and use V2 instead of D2 */
proc sql;
create view V2 as select * from D2 order by stock Date_Time;
quit;

data d3;
set d2 /* or use V2 if created the view */;
by stock Date_Time;
    if first.stock = 1 then output;/* first row always kept for the stock */
    else do;
        time_diff=dif(Date_Time)/60; 
        if time_diff > 30 then output;
    end;
run;
```

Updated (didn't try it) to delete all records closer than 30 sec from last kept record:

```
data d3;
set d2 /* or use V2 if created the view */;
retain last_kept_dt;
by stock Date_Time;
    if first.stock = 1 then do;
        last_kept_dt = Date_Time;
        output;/* first row always kept for the stock */
    end;
    else do;
        time_diff = (Date_Time - last_kept_dt)/60;
        if time_diff > 30 then do;
             output;
             last_kept_dt = Date_Time;
          end;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: I don't actually use numbers as table names...just for the example! Thanks for your help.  I would like to delete all the rows that are 30 minutes apart, not just one of them...do you know if this is possible? For instance, if I had two stocks that traded 25 minutes apart, I'd like to delete both of them.

Comment: im getting an error that the do loop has not properly been closed. I tried fixing the end statements but to it didn't work...same error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way of doing this that I think works. It adds the following code:

```
proc expand data=3 out=4 method=none; 
convert delete=delete_lead1 / transformout=(lead 1); 
run;
```

Now this gives me a dataset with a delete variable from my first step and a lead variable (delete_lead1) that will give a value of one to the other row I need to delete.  I checked all the observations and it works even for 4 or 5 rows together so I have more confidence in this solution.